# New button pop is not showing to create new record in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, onclick, new

i am new to lightning and trying to learn lightning. i have created component in that component i am showing the contact based on the accountid using (implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId") which is working fine it;s showing data and i have added "new" button so that i can create another contact based on the accountid but it's not showing popup so unable to create record. below is component

```
   <aura:set attribute="actions">
        <lightning:button label="New" onClick="{!c.newContact}" />
    </aura:set>
```

-------------below is my component controller-----------------------------

```
newContact: function(component, event, helper){
    var createContact = $A.get("e.force.createRecord");
    alert(createContact);
    createContact.setParams({
        'entityApiName': 'Contact',
        'defaultfieldValues': {
            'AccountId': component.get("v.recordId")
        }
    });
    createContact.fire();
}
```

Comment: Are you testing this component in app? or you added this component in account detail page?

Comment: One problem is that `defaultfieldValues` should be `defaultFieldValues` as Aura/JavaScript is case sensitive. There is a small chance that is causing the problem.

Comment: i have tried Capital F in defaultFieldValues... but it didn't worked

Comment: @ratan i have added component on Record page.. i know in app it will not work because accountid(recordId) was not there

Comment: @KeithC if i use defaultFieldValues then it show "Uncaught Action failed: c:MyContactComp$controller$newContact [Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined]"

Comment: That sounds like `createContact` is undefined but I presume you still have the `alert` that confirms it is defined?